# How do you redirect back to a method in Java?

Tags: java

I wanted to know how to redirect back to a method in java. For testing purposes when I run it it asks what I want to do. I choose deposit(for testing purposes) and I purposely enter an amount lower than $250. It returns the prompt I want it to, but the program just ends. I want to redirect the program back to the beginning of the deposit method so the program keeps on going. I know I could just write the deposit method again in the if, else if statement of the deposit section but I would rather have the program redirect. This program is just for fun. I am kind of new to programming so if I am mislabeling anything, please correct me nicely. Here is the full program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class TestException
{
  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
     Scanner awith = new Scanner(System.in);

     double bal = 0000.00;
     System.out.println("Deposit - D      Withdraw - W      Balance - B");       
     System.out.println("Would you like to deposit, withdraw, or check balance?");
     String a = awith.nextLine();
     if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
     {
         System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
         double g = awith.nextDouble();

         if(g < 250.00)
         {
             System.out.println("Minimum of $250.00 must be deposited");
         }
         else if(g >= 250.00)
         {
         System.out.println("You deposited: $" + g);
         double newbal = bal + g;
         System.out.println("Your new balance is: $" + newbal);
         System.out.println("Thank you for using Folders Bank!");
        }
     }
     else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
     {
         System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
         double x = awith.nextDouble();

         if(x > bal)
         {
             System.out.println("Invalid amount chosen for withdrawal!");
         }
         else if(x < 0.01)
         {
             System.out.println("Invalid amount chosen for withdrawal!");
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("You have successfully withdrew: $" + x);
             double newbal1 = bal - x;
             System.out.println("Your new balance is: $" + newbal1);
             System.out.println("Thank you for using Folders Bank!");
         }
     }
     else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
     {   
        if(bal == 0.00)
        {
             System.out.println("You have an empty balance. Please deposit money.");
        }
        else if(bal >= 250.00)
        {
         System.out.println("Your balance is: $" + bal);
         System.out.println("Thank you for using Folders Bank!");
        }
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Invalid entry! Thank you for using Folders Bank!");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: put a loop around your logic. But don't forget an exit option

Comment: Why didn't I think about a loop? Thanks.

Comment: Use a while loop and make sure the cryteria on which is looping is "as long as you read something different from " and you put your exiting condition

Answer (score 0):

You can do following :
from line no 09

```
System.out.println("Would you like to deposit, withdraw, or check balance and Exit(e)?");
String a = awith.next();
while(a.equalsIgnoreCase("e")!=true)
{
//yourcode
//all of your if conditions
System.out.println("Would you like to deposit, withdraw, or check balance and Exit(e)?");
a = awith.next();
}
```

you can also use do while, if you dont want to get last two line two times.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Ajit's solution will work, I'd suggest to use `do.. while` instead of just `while`, because with `while` you have to repeat the prompt and scan - like this:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to deposit, withdraw, or check balance and Exit(e)?");
    a = awith.next();    
} while ( ! a.equalsIgnoreCase("e"));
```